# Create an image in tkinter with just image data?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to create an image in tkinter but I want to use the image data instead of passing in a file. How do I do that? Here's how I'm creating an image.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

global myimage
myimage = PhotoImage(data="IMAGE DATA HERE")

mytext = Text(root, width=100, height=50, )
mytext.pack()

mytext.image_create(END, image=myimage)


root.mainloop()
```

When using this method i get an error saying that `could not recognize image data`

Quick note I used a python script to convert the image into bytes.

here is the data:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAgICAgJCAkKCgkNDgwODRMSEBASEx0VFhUWFR0sHCAcHCAcLCcvJiQmLydGNzExN0ZRREBEUWJYWGJ8dnyiotkBCAgICAkICQoKCQ0ODA4NExIQEBITHRUWFRYVHSwcIBwcIBwsJy8mJCYvJ0Y3MTE3RlFEQERRYlhYYnx2fKKi2f/CABEIBxkD/AMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAA2AAACAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAADBAECBQAGBwgBAAIDAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIDAAEEBQYHCP/aAAwDAQACEAMQAAAA+IRbui+kXjMNYvCl1mZhxM8d9FuCUaXPRB6wSk2EW2z0dCnomTqXrA6hOtcX6gtv3Wj+tFo3omINa3ra4ieiaxaIMFHaM6JmNpBKyd01gz0RBt0dA7o6VeaTG3mk068Rajjp6ijp4RrExAme5gxFqkU90LkV6sV3XsYDm/HdJt1XWZkWVmYkt1eqdW3VB1PS0CtMWq9hTDPUcHd6RETHdMqe7hnd3Vfd1ocTPST0dLtETJHd1TonhqLVtZd3dCju6B3dwq7u6D3d1lPRPUb3d2OdFuSqvTB13d1yY6ButhSAPqGHTAErci7u6y7u6X3ccSHNhmVLTxSCUuDLdHUVojrKaXiXWLxBpFugV6elVvXpdqdFLtWYiY6eKonuldExc6Y6rma9TCEFcdVur1Hbq9K7u6qmekpWLRdUiOtXTe1lW3dZd3ddd0RRT1eEIrFYm0U6AWwrU48VsTIqTqAPGioHiwSRQSsGlumSev0KnX6XWZ6r6JiDETEVFomSe7hOOmBHpibnd3Q47uk7u6L7u6V3dxVWa9uZa1Jzlfo4VRE1EZiOq+6Jk6pByraOVqpbq+aeSso6eauOmJO9F51lb/W+O+j+Sy78Swb7skXpNhaOrUtNLRt5raN6JiVETEHjBYql6aGbF9FiWitbxKjpi77ukriLdcp14oKdaBnWrwMt1eo7dXrYS1Lw7d0mcVtEgpv1DNq8RTWeqqxFbXaK1iLdSBXbuvBpxOkH1oki4bQz2DNsLwohF4cwrR0wYi0QY6vWN+p1Vfq9Anomq7utDie6N6J6gju6hiYmX3d0OO7oHd3RXd3XXd3WPdWdb5i1qg5rZS5peq5Xu6FM9A3PVJYxSYqHFxBZXq2NkdboUULFFpgS4CrfuYuJnrGvd1Bee6PiLTG16k0DSr+bBv0ySqdeCkd3XXUtUR6Jiq6JiVNxxcNYFiYSvXlU61BqlbQFcSl7bea2J0z1rb3TAnNYpAnhdEFHUdpmOkldM2kpJJkDboGprMyq26Ku1e6pWLxddNel27ul9MdQz3dddMVl2mCS5mOkiJiriYmNt3dToiepcd3QYnuse7uk7u6D1q2MIratXHdNLHMToYQy7D9K1prmTMdyqjp6SImoDa1Ig3rFpIKObbFxkjrTSYy0kWkvanXL1msu8Vtcr3dYXnujI6aSU4tImvFgr6wrwZjoqdXooOiYgx3dK6JiTq2moOZrQkuG1kakSZ1i3VItEiVpr0cW4pMyVjoVak6CCphjnFW8Wnr1khveloRJrMuBkHQRcdqq0d0IdpuJRxJKgQxB2DiRKH14VVemRrrXtVV6R2Fet1n0TEuJiYy3dNMiJ6jjp6hr08WeOnrqOnquJ6LGYnodemIFO6SCrKxteggGFwuJrfMEx1YHVngCtpoVWr2kLc+fY4iG5cUnQm9YmHPUvcvXohX6loU2HeFHTUjL1bRkTXrrr1ua7V6tiOsjEb9WQGe7qnRNSruiZXRaJInphRFulUreo1JBkud09Z9E8J9FohV6tTWe4TE+89MfQJwCoXR0w90dUtakyXkfSFrbpYovShuQZpL9ejjjq9KtNJhWi3DKVvC6p08NRFpERyYhCCTDuhRasqJiaO091F3R1F3d1D3dzK7ulpR3QNTWYWHWrMZNZrKpeIoLDntN9FuadSDnPURFxV0OFos271RintPGkB3u/GIwq6z06c0T0mXdMyxwWskkpwMmKwMJW0E3r33Q0+fnewWM7uGee9xnigjNEoMEHQ9alqqa3iSklHcm0cZT0RKivQI9McFWtF7vq9WFN6GF09fppWEwEsksrHKydHFo4ReoVatDHOvJuoRcWsoc9NDM066tToobFEQqJ1JZd5HxESK8BxNagJIHFCSIioQqpJGYDx1eBxYFp16AfEgSiI4J09wn3T0uOmTkz1tBDqSixjphQRFq2cd3HcRMLk93GL6Wgo5oa3GK4tHCskRYX0t1xAE2pAm1LUNbRNzpiSvpiZO7uh9EQLLWGUWWvNS0nbzppzC0iMSUgsCaGXgVLSTDhkiLH14oa1tElunrus1colatqQaxbrCJm1F09ELu4gnF54dN+ipGIVqXhm4+IWJBeMMQZ5rGJmkoUkFF2kF6GRGrItUwwRXp6ItavHL2re5Wthy7WHcWTF7U0XFiCKL1gRekku/R1h3dMrrxFS9Y6pXrcFd3SBxM9ZRPcy7WrLyilqKG1ZqoOrapnHdzLraw0hWtrhXMLs6NdVNJN9BtMIzTbrA2vVEsC9Frrum8qvXm7pNps6UPSiHa1rsXFrTZixwYCXEjKOpEVenXsIZHemUHMS7dHGMRaDGLda5WholjsSst30vkKqZsYBaEmnTxqm0XFlakoBVuIko1rRemo7iNI4nixR15jBGIwOqhZpWy0V6Tgn6gQG8rMcmVYquExQGr9el4er0mJSCsckBKgdS1KOmesGiJFJupqQcWPutaImLUPXrapasxcjrdCiekJE91F3dxlNLVMbzSzJWtqhO6IUFqzxlXp4rIInKABqkAgFrL3u0N6Hfq8cPVxcnPPet0GKjAwVQktQlrFEV93da5mJu56JK46sQiA6KLQ9f4cqNG15yIgVmvOzEkcixmI6aa90lK9N7lZ7rubVvCipYuxwWsukXDFd01ia3g1FWxIjhUL1KBa1pROrY3iCUZ5ui0WiXxaU6YhGitohOKDnrMVgWsLhA4YvUVqwqOY/CvR0CzSLCTuPPWevUoQs3prNKS4pHDnk4DSyAZretc0xEdXqAHTNrCJ7ivp7pfTEgPR3VO7uudW1TnWrNyYmJVa24AraJhdWa0TOiosN1HetVW9qEb7WNG191y0mUvUnNU9aq1n18PRFmz5X2HkCb0xzM1uibkxPFOFfodBmFVdYd6Ka26r6wiS+juszWrw6OtTrl+HFwnUtRdE1qpsO0oxbuTqKQ5FvGA61pHQ95lD2j0149NJMcITULa5EwuTKDt146XI0WijYyTfW1hW2RF68whnBFRHSvMKSQNUVZWDPS1oibXDMcxZbjNqtLEdhR1UPrDmaZmxhSxqW2pILTBjbqJLV0OqZ5YunNSekjiemriLQIx3dK7u4p0TB3HTWXPRNB3WrV1oSqrktmU7VuC6/ChabUsdCDkp0w+rEGbddaXpmOxKFSm00iDcVutlemZUT3S5nuKSMo4dKXrQD6bSidW8ePiXjhSccK0TWMr1ZiIJ1rleiKbPRargslprhxTfdqoyleWtZg8BXs5qanloAOuZBYcbVSGPXmVf9KGfxRtBC1GNxi6K7yLshsplQgrUlbyLQbpnDU4gV1+kSCA1QUGL2HNS15hLiYCa7WHpvirmvp9zo+cr6BTrTL2R7Gl1PO7eCukNcTvMx9W0V1rBIPIHnqzTz/Et3SI93RV2r00FenrGO6HTprxya2gLiYtUmO4SqxVzJvtfqZeuuP2vlNHnOzm6NyrxFyWvRgbCg9Guo4YmB2XTFsCR3rIrvNrwg1LSVWetUiZIR3tLMdkQasSva1INZ4kdW1a20lYvGV7og3mSSh8QcKsGbrUBoxa66XaVLaC1hXdVi9eNbmKmgVr0gzFOGoi8QGDpmHZ67c8pkr1uZLVXLi65JdaNVql+iLQSa2qorNKoczqVMqu6i2s2usfUGFX0WaxKlmnHQL2ox0uplA38uczJSaKhOU7s84stqZ0nm5+inzeQRjEexntUVLs6w1Lpc3MKOjChmnRVTWaqrr0tB7u4pWJjdItW4yy7KyB4g7hcWg+fWVilsnUisQi/fZPbzcvyvQ5bZxxVcRBLbCR2lXq06DmFma9K17WrzEV4ts6qlXJL6s9JBKnseua5EAbMRyw2KVStGq0TiV4j6jNYrUlil2O5L2oNicLB1YiaymDYeiQyjE3Nda03KBYWvAK9Kljvw5tdx2iWHr9aKdetDE3rBpMSJmuvWM4ykhn1Q0JOjSYIY1lpnY3NtrW2lm6tO2aGQVIxl4niannaqSMAGlrMwbNEyaNSUNejy4Ml9q3Xavj7WFqI1D2pEeR9T4rheXHvee9fyuyNP1I9Pf8nG+HHn8lpD9Pi4/nE9HPOdaJxqpasiHd3FdYmNtxW1ViSscq7dLGdkGYFk7MQOoDalB1n3PX/OfSdXrW8j7jy2ZFBr6Neayz9Fqt030Og4O7BXKubKgqxK5k0reJdYm4nzQnbl+vW4G8SUr15pitGYpq8GimiPQ8KimpnwBk4hhNuvWwYz1HaObSOihg0l6F86ZpZDS0GRMUigVKvMkSPiQxcF7K9KiKnJXKt8UPAEsNuaBGmiFeMbazFzQagnsetNw33ar9SUvLEcBd1qLkzWwMAm4qHOE4EzMz1x36uts41DRu3XZzYs7F9DgbjY4yqcHnsrUzuVhR9t4r3PK6e2BmNHusOr62bkZvoqEV5vxOdr5Uy9eLcxA+6AqetU2Vie2XXuhId3XznbTC1k7UAvGLWELqp4wwYxpzSkR9RyPSdk7vM9L5qW0UeeZWvUM14kwiva07gZo/JozbBs1836kKL2OZ8zBGytqXAade4DWZkHr1NEMVTUBtaEkbDfr1dLTxaeKM1axBKIWjtECNx91h1uvZjtSBs3C6i4N62gcEraJMEt0avH0ErD3ManZjkEvLMI0LiJYErtCsWLS4ZPbOkoOc5my5sG+a3gXQcLFHPdRjhpvivAo1Q9A3ZgexTpJVPpPsJdn5zXmdrF3W9h7mCvg5Kba/OUl73wXvOH0vQrNYU9uHzZ8zB5L3shN1ud5TK9Bgiml5ryc1evKarW/PYOhKand3WygJy7WPqV6nZN1oqMRupxrxmbufPvyE9HvpnlM73Pi9bz3Y954T3KHneh80pvYmvzFmE7FnfIibPn0Iy6bAvJF+luYFPFGX0/bb9uD31lam/Jp3O058j0EapMwg6ye3SoUzTWZeT6fE5wgDq5uNIZ42UgceV9Ba9qoeIbVUwNdKpBmSxQApN6sYChoixwWJBdaCVMk9iqvE9tYjKHcfEljgXAiEHZbD3ESaRzUcCIHN5Hm13fbX3Qqdt3ScwdO1bhJ5SrEFzFa0M56WCzImYZwt4Da7XtUEpoD0HC1qdgovq68I83TwZyk12zJ5eN6/ELwN255wYec+CCdXi9G9navavzeB6PzwY+GSOUqLTyLgZqtYKrQzeq7TVw7pEUGTqjpcA5QgtdnNl+jKeg80JnH2fOMZeh9W8KJPQQys2OXf8r6vBUOsHkKTat5rHVPcOtcbj3ENnOVyUurbsdV/6V8s9z0uj9jyz+aw151oBO/psmsyTaKOCYAr26aex9rK5LERHnPlz2QWWgpKkvcqFkeN9uPKjCAonLD3TmCJmpF1ulqYpJbpWp60oOzmQE001rUIBk4kDm9RGejqIzCTA67rWVtBGV9B2Bs9tP1mrJr7LXyH84t9Z0cmf46/9eaTi+U6X0qyEfPC/QmFB4F33jSE+Jv7WmbT86+c/cvkHS9thrFp2ehruZx6dmWoY0lxfQZCOLl6latdnqsh4SU+JTn444lBL1eyptdA/L+c91j5V+O6CI5VIngHjU1b2qpMmz9KxWk8vSDW4KzATME+ddujwPqzFlb9BhAyen4x7NL7n5/tqXns2Pa87t+X9Injejx8HPSmLHw4vWAO54ICtXNpGoRXrbqdDvY+W9Dt3fScVX0G0/McwHejM1sxmiMu6nn0MQeAex570XnswpHEbLFwtrrZUkynbPTKXUARYapUnO569SBy1ekxV9esmqtuhi+oURqvUVCSxSkkHULqWvBp7fZXn+Xs/XnxT8i0vrrg4/kGh9bemb596L0l5ycttklJDDvLiRD9WwRqkXsnrVHVcytluailIwh0WgK/yX6p8929r5iUTnpPXksvRUCZZqqMg1nXyLZziAMXoWORylOITOslX6Jd6Dd8t6QdkZc5aUeVtxX8VWSaiGVFqYiexXWOJHSArZalcjZd3K5qmgtlTsET0163oS78BNgZEWp2PKOaGPo+goWglbF09RF1Lh7smH074FYIS0zDJCLNLcW197jtoYxvec9T0ehre085o7tbHmvW+PZiEMRNBaqDi+Q2RDuNmytzNiMwsF5zVVGFkia1DL6AuNUYuJyQSnJhOGibyWSh8XZAsCdl1mTy9/abJc/50T67rTl/Edf7QU+d8x3fZPTN5ZrSi0Is2YC6CeqMVluwa1TsSOmWaSgC8CBIwBhvSQYqzQcisi1yVLCbEgkWtwpWW+TJOTyeX9DjO2/IWpF6T1NatArKq8kwWi+XqJFgSWYTxcvpmnOyWYCxRtmKfH0F/Red38+zzOJt4zuWmVit4r6EUz9tLTMwjetntp4mqIaOZo4oblaLLXQnRy+iGHRzq0JqtZW7hAVrGnjkD3OwVYD20dQaxd2rXSaQ4nXGsWUccRTLtWw0m83PqYzgHFm3vG3T3ocDma/sCPzr03T1e+8X6zzmrLiuSztrubLkzIuLshiYRsuL8u1Jy7QLtrZTKxUq9AQuXmJDtnZXh8QL6prng+R631UieR4n1b165uQ45eYQs9a7rU5V7VB6N17k3LUR0w9fq11mvUwnU6irERCuOYGFKpNCeAwJkqKlMNQFZpPQVKexZXhc5Kk3CiBMczZUTD20Olo/OMf1XnOv3SLOovxrTYml4BdZwZ67IuRw1oaBmRaR8a32MjRXvafFp49vl1toFc4DugJHSzjdsZOkrt4OxgNrz/pH+dn+PY31vxPUxYmvfTbroa1U9UeW5iv5YMZhPdwLDKFmC1+rAqVh1ywMWP0FMJbLeLpeNnQz8KtIF29GHPMzdoKruUJmZdomrUmvsLMNz3fiPoPTwSvrpdLnZBSczpNvK0z8xYdVr0kFawbMojhsgZZd5hGHIbffnKR2BMDxtMyjCcpqtMAzNJo8ti8vHXvRZPOfqxaKr6JYFw6aiNFtDQwaZEU6Ov1LVUilemFgEwzcCaheFAQlBUppaCHTS1DWnGpAado2TNSxyG5PKZc1wSpQtbciBXsR8l67zPUafC2cXoYrXYEyZ1qTtpMBxcHkD6bZ1g4nFS2wk2bvS+i8x6nj6lkNbHznmrLNaGNXCvg6AkG8tIh08BkM++wptI6i4tBFzxony2Y08a4eh52ktcFIKsrash55xSGmC87EpBg6Qb9B5r1+XfnYnqsYOeg0625GQHdzWTLYs3Tri1S6xx9Eu7szI7yLL8N0Xg9BiQm17aJJomfNni2CVMvSY3FY8Jn0JlIx52zBXn9HWsq85xkynRe0pZMVHcL1LyjsqHT0i8Kc3SvEcGrpioaJitYfBIC3VrEU8thWoYWZXjhxI4+bBuJkrwwqaxFFFJHTor1IyegdMNUc0RYpchKdW9qOuNZzYMIulovPen8t1Ry6h2+wmmFuY48lO7S2vfnhsHzvEYJDOoxK6mdnzyaGJo2fW+Q9RyNU+R1vNBYdEBnBRBlXnPXUbZpaO1bZydWDXXDpznOYZgLzrCG/hi0BMBnhBrNlq8a+7mi0DGzaXKWHu82JRyhnf2Xk/aMzM4HtfM4eYgQee3cwBPrfoaGVsMSW7U68ltVZjXkE0N8lFppALm5w3asaItohQsRE2G2cbcVZO6+aXKMwHPTYGWOIimG6l16AiKJmUthWhlOobPsZutfP2DUrAbbRWotmkwL6jJWNDQ4o+bTAjwripowkHH0uSaOg54YOpR0dBkHTh1tSMiaxR17uGy2FYhIofPMyHUdayh6w9bOBvtbsnhzWX7SFmhjcAMLdxGZM0BK8HmalqD7BO5mrmYedZhQodLY3MLW5fRXQ3cpGlWVISZ8+KBlJtB3cfRGaRBtGMfW4HldHB38dc0ml2go87EUWxbePQbXGn2q3o1OT7LzFn1PRfNFyWP0MgvZeW9Yzmep8p7Ty3msPj8rXxGelLRm1XOvnbuvC6S9tfNoyNvQFjDGzPvBip5aUqJx1FXjbWCXsy62e/ms5AnzyxBlUc3gq3cTrKPotSFShOPPW/WpkFrdO2bROfsTHQrb0dFHETWnxHRT6iIKaDRMANRlHRr0LSPmJpR07uq+peBsQyjjQ0LSnUratMr3RV3mlrk5umgxi588jtGldArl6qhV9eLx7+e36jzt8+do7X816Tzlc7IG3TDrZINjRWpgu5uLjUIE2fqbG7kX5urWxQq4t1Q3h2fmiaS+lLyLeXWwqZUHCxiYGnEMfA1c5o+dsZdtAaGWoUp5rZy6jaujV9Bz9Zbnd/wA8rqY3f8Q5dOezwC7WFV+X7H5oV/H5PP8Am/eePnZCe0MPtrzu7txaLaOrt5xmBQ7LyRUC1b5MnVfhXgtdFL3FxvuPuotTRSfx1YtSJK5IulljDOl8zblNpF5pg+P1GCbxL6ZgXzPcndETUNXRHQ+rNRd1ZitVQlDWs/dILil61YIJMaETAKZSbTRUreBsQjCjRUJSmjrelMpE1pkzWbu1pISspXb5z8a+qu44003tGTx4H8r1XmQ7eYlfPpnDv0eiqTc3cOzxdHECFeejm5a7ufr8fdOdVfOi1A1rM0wHaVovocQOtUDVgEGK95p2dWhQbcKi78JmfvZLaGbHntnJDQvoVYatKHyKf9IUbSFGd531WPrz+OJ6KnX8yDO2sLcEex8VqcEfofnnGMWbLx/Y+XW5DVR1dwn28ra2cki7K70hQdyw6TfofIej1ZGwWDrwoWDRuzQ0sPfTT5Blx0U4SKMxBnQy5hlS8nTdLx3tYXUmtgdSpRlcRbhkd0DpitqjoiZtGDqWovFWw61wO1a1FuI4VShRiI5tWHUB6UwV6koxUvFWEZR04YyijaVtQWUGUVHPdWzJNJICmBJiQgzvTaaEevB8f9A8T6rCbI0td/N+earmH0en6pPFWyqYGC6jsZFrgN3sZ/A4eq9UrnzGGA+hAy7Mmzb4mGmZ103MbVgyUdBHfhBS7SegrVwWfcnR6JkKlpBE6U2FjsLRNEs2+OorWTP0UJFAwXteRB5X2Pld9o6wHMuo3t/BfQeHzC+Q9F5TPoM1naG6tHVzG9POOrSHAqjpZY9Qe55fXMvRQE3S8+qk6A9Tezka+a2yhNkoxRGU0xwlQwpgGS8pBXRov0dRxFqVdaxxLtPSrdETAvrFoptZ6tNtSa1ooMlJrHW4xfdlZgZNbwKqwQFXwTVjh1uOjF0xTKhJSmrxYUdWpACUq+a+fXj+1T8q+l1qbmOLQW1LEJDrn0Jlc6GkmfN72L2OchJfN9nL67zrrpbvFK72MfHEAyGB1Br286btAdkYw3X1UDP9TV/NrB1ph3Ytl7uAJFoW7kp5ja1dIMyJHRJYb6X0BoLliM43pR+eDbSOh+Zcyz5/vFmV1dMqjAsrcOhMntea28mtO5yzjDRBk9Z59vnju5zrHL253aQNPNiy1dGNjg0h9lmT2dUDiN8uv1DeHpdjypeF0t7UzdJBOlWNljZlzJaywq3mdcwy53kvFkv6LVq4HcVpi8ljhcWmfqVi0Q6RaI6tLxRxW/UwVDDrQIZxx1ThKJX6OFXALm0T8fH/AA0y/pDvzV6Or+3R4L1A79AdxzVUJopy3hG/kBcmEZ6+G39j+K/XF9720VsXfJaljAjKrOnG1n6Gdpzzna2Tvvzeol6fs+E8Wn7THZWf5r0nmWbM9U9eF1x00b8g8U7TdXr+xy93TzJjiLIdSI0NlBk6HNvnnzUdIAjruEI2HQWnoGsGgJmHruzoGa3BIGgnl+X9NmTH6sTgUiILIMfbwsPWwOliug9mdzzrXBnCre0vM7bk+nfQ3uE3KrYGjDQehfQhXO9HiSshR5Hp9hQRFc2/d1vP6/T808vPNQzvo6GWiMKsoJkwC53tNJs5tBzgdy6YvW6T6tBHmJMsq1hLeytwKHCGitJsRjralO6sZtM04zX6KazMaKpKw6X7hOZr1Df4r9p/PdZ/AB7q5MT3Qiej81ST7h7X8x+qrqffvG+V8LCDm0JfLtFZsS/V/lX1hXo/YXWvfeausVuY5lb6Mjw6NPXm5XqFN+TD7W8p2fnW2tjVM87z21jp9ImcjXHBeXl86WdYGrqQ6zyai0CgCrQLAMppQFu5pJT1bDoQu8bTxlGL0LImO0o6mqyiMdz5kpHoXf8AJ78Vs+b9JgN4rC+WTge/YBYWPu5GR6DD6fJbzW1fVfO4C+LUzM38bZwK9jsYOhyeAJnTKfIyWOC7okxdbED
```

Comment: Tk's `PhotoImage` supports only a few image formats. If the image is, for example a JPG, you can use PIL / pillow.

Comment: There's an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71085099/7432

Comment: i tried the example and its still giving me the same error on `myimage = tk.PhotoImage(data=imageData)`  @BryanOakley

Comment: That's telling you the image isn't a supported format. Did you start with a gif or png and then encode it in base64 before adding it to the program?

Comment: my script is designed to decode the image in base64. I tried it again with a png and it had the same problem. however my image data looks a little different than the one in the example as mine has forward slashes in it.  @BryanOakley

Comment: You need to show us the data. Bottom line is that your code is fine, but your data is corrupted. Since we can't see your data we're not going to be able to give any useful advice. Also, you don't need to write any code to decode the data. You can give the base64-encoded data directly to the `data` option, as shown in the answer I provided a link to.

Comment: I updated my question to show the image data i got from the script.  @BryanOakley

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem is the data, just like what the error is telling you. The original format of your data is jpeg, and tkinter doesn't natively support jpeg.

You will need to either convert the original image to GIF or PNG before encoding it, or use pillow to convert it before handing it off to tkinter.